# How to remove zeros from decimal numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math, decimal, rounding

If the calculation for example is `10/8` the code should answer `1.25` instead of `1.250` or `0/1` should be `0` instead of `0.000`. How does one remove zeros from decimal numbers in Javascript while still keeping the max amount of digits (if no zeros) after the dot three (`.toFixed(3);`)

```js
var operator = ['/'];

function F1() {    
    Z1 = document.getElementById("Z1");
    Z2 = document.getElementById("Z2");
    oper=document.getElementById("operator");
    answer=document.getElementById("answer");
     
    rZ1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10));
    rZ2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
    op = operator[Math.floor(Math.random()*1)];
     
    Z1.innerHTML=rZ1; Z2.innerHTML=rZ2;
    oper.innerHTML=op;
    answer.innerHTML = eval(rZ1 + op + rZ2).toFixed(3);}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>
<p> <label id="Z1"> </label> 
    <label id="operator"> </label>
    <label id="Z2"> </label>
  = <label id="answer"> </label> </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but this works:

```js
var operator = ['/'];

function F1() {    
    Z1 = document.getElementById("Z1");
    Z2 = document.getElementById("Z2");
    oper=document.getElementById("operator");
    answer=document.getElementById("answer");
     
    rZ1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10));
    rZ2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
    op = operator[Math.floor(Math.random()*1)];
     
    Z1.innerHTML=rZ1; Z2.innerHTML=rZ2;
    oper.innerHTML=op;
    var blah = parseFloat(eval(rZ1 + op + rZ2).toFixed(3));
    if (blah.toFixed(2) == blah) {
      blah = parseFloat(blah.toFixed(2));
      if (blah.toFixed(1) == blah) {
        blah = parseFloat(blah.toFixed(1));
      }
    }
    answer.innerHTML = blah;}
```

```html
<button onclick="F1()"> New </button>
<p> <label id="Z1"> </label> 
    <label id="operator"> </label>
    <label id="Z2"> </label>
  = <label id="answer"> </label> </p>
```